# ASP.NET MVC : Ignore latter route elements in url for a form's action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, url, routes

I have a URL /products/search where Products is the controller and Search is the action. This url contains a search form whose action attribute is (and should always be) /products/search eg;

```
<%using( Html.BeginForm( "search", "products", FormMethod.Post))
```

This works ok until I introduce paging in the search results. For example if I search for "t" I get a paged list. So on page 2 my url looks like this :

```
/products/search/t/2
```

It shows page 2 of the result set for the search "t". The problem is that the form action is now also /products/search/t/2. I want the form to always post to /products/search.

My routes are :

```
routes.MapRoute( "Products search",
        "products/search/{query}/{page}",
        new { controller = "Products", action = "Search", query = "", page = 1 });

routes.MapRoute( "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

How can I force Html.BeginForm(), or more specifically Url.Action( "Search", "Products"), to ignore the /query/page in the url?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding another route where query and page are not in the url which is kind of counter intuitive because the more specific route is lower down the order

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "",
        "products/search",
        new { controller = "Products", action = "Search", query = "", page = 1 });

routes.MapRoute(
        "",
        "products/search/{query}/{page}",
        new { controller = "Products", action = "Search"} //, query = "", page = 1 });

routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

Answer (score 0):

The order is really important, the first route it hits that matches it uses. Therefore catch all type routes should be at the very end. Here is a helpful route debugger youc an use to figure out what the problem is.

[Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, the problem then is that the search query and page values appear as query parameters in the url like this :

/products/search?query=r&page=2

rather than

/products/search/r/2

So it seems like a routing catch 22

Comment: Well if you have no objection and you want a clean url you should use a post instead of a get when you form submits. Otherwise if you setup your routing properly in the global.asax your url should look fine. ex: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{page}"